When is the value of a rowversion column actually set
When exactly is a rowversion column value generated when it comes to long running transactions?
Example: if there is a transaction A and a transaction B.
Transaction A was started 10 minutes ago and took 8 minutes to complete. Transaction B was started 6 minutes ago, but completed after 1 minute.
Which of the transactions will have the lower rowversion value?
Unfortunately the Microsoft documentation is not explaining this.

I would question why you need to know this?  You should be avoiding long running transactions

"You can use the rowversion column of a row to easily determine whether an update statement has been run against the row since the last time it was read. If an update statement is run against the row, the rowversion value is updated. If no update statements are run against the row, the rowversion value is the same as when it was previously read." - that's it's only valid use

The context is the following: A very legacy mssql database that is used by a lot of different processes in very different situations, which we need to extract data from. I have no way of preventing long running transactions (which as you pointed out, are not a good idea).

I suspect you might have an XY problem.

@phil once again, why are you asking? The value is set immediately as anyone is concerned. That value is only used for optimistic concurrency anyway, so all anyone cares is whether the value changed since the row was read. Nothing else. It's not meant for indexing, not meant for change detection, not meant for range searches. Just difference checks for this specific row. There's no guarantee that new values will be consecutive or that they'll specify the change order. If you use rowversion for change detection you'll lose changes

@phil change tracking is the job of the Change Tracking feature, available in all versions and editions since at least 2005 or 2008 (can't remember). Retrieving all changes, including deletions, since the last check only requires a JOIN with the CHANGETABLE function

@phil the answer to Which of the transactions will have the lower rowversion value? is Nobody cares. If you do, you have a bug

The execution plan will call the internal function gettimestamp for each row and so it will be whenever that is called. It is going to be non deterministic and entirely independent of transaction start times. If execution plan for A had a blocking operator like a sort it could possibly be evaluated after transaction B has already packed up and gone home.

@MartinSmith I suspect even that is a legacy name that hides something like Interlocked.Increment, with possible buffering to reduce contention in multi-core operations. I tried to use rowversion for change detection a decade or more ago too, and found there are jumps in the values. Then I remembered the restrictions on the value were weakened somewhere around 2008 or earlier

Could well work in a similar manner to identity/sequences (where it just persistently records a high water mark and increments that in batches and doesn't care if some are unused)

Thank you very much for the insights. We are currently trying to use a combination of UpdateTimestamp and a rowversion column for change tracking. I have to dig deeper into the Change Tracking Feature, that much I have understood.

Is the problem you're trying to solve a "corehent" view of some data in your db? Are you using (NOLOCK)s when reading it? You seem to keep avoiding answering questions

@phil you need to explain the actual business problem. Change tracking will show you which rows or were deleted and even which columns changed but won't tell you what the previous values were. For that you need temporal tables, or the more expensive CDC. You can't use rowversion for row tracking - guess how we all found that out. An updated column is useful for reporting if you don't use temporal tables.

IMO,Good question.

Thank you for clarifying the internal mechanics, @Martin Smith. This is precisely the information I needed. My explanations are limited due to the constraints on my available options. We're attempting to replicate database changes to Kafka using JDBC Connectors, which operate by querying the database tables with a high watermark. The ideal methods, such as CDC and CT, are not viable to us because they have been vetoed by the database administrators due to previous performance issues. Therefore, I am trying make the most of what is an imperfect situation.

"The ideal methods, such as CDC and CT, are not viable to us because they have been vetoed by the database administrators due to previous performance issues." - sounds like a them problem! CDC is EXACTLY what you should be using.
